# Cannot run PHP debugging in Netbeans - XDebug

Tags: php, netbeans, xdebug

I have Netbeans **7.0.1** IDE, running on Windows **7 64-bit**. I have installed the PHP through **XAMPP 1.7.2**. Running `phpinfo()` shows PHP version as **5.3.1** and XDebug version as **2.0.6-dev**.

A web-page on [netbeans.org](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/php/configure-php-environment-windows.html) has mentioned some entries to be uncommented in **php.ini** file, and has mentioned that compatible XDebug.dll is already provided with the setup.
These are entries from the **php.ini** file...

```
[PECL]
zend_extension = "C:\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug.dll"

[XDebug]
xdebug.remote_port = 9000
xdebug.remote_host = 127.0.0.1
xdebug.remote_handler = "dbgp"
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.profiler_enable = 0
xdebug.profiler_append = 0
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger = 0
xdebug.profiler_output_name = "xdebug_profile.%p"
xdebug.profiler_output_dir = "C:\xampp\tmp"
xdebug.trace_output_dir = "C:\xampp\tmp"
xdebug.idekey = "netbeans-xdebug"
```

Heres is the snapshot of the debugger configuration from Netbeans IDE.
[image]

The **Sessions** debugger window doesn't show **netbeans-xdebug** session running.
[image]

After all these settings, the debugger is still not running.

I checked the ports using **TCPView** and it shows that port 9000 is free. Also the firewall is disabled.

Any help please?

Answer (score 0):

```
[zend]
zend_extension = "path_to_xdebug"
xdebug.remote_enable=On
xdebug.remote_host="localhost"
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_handler="dbgp"
xdebug.profiler_enable = On 
xdebug.profiler_output_dir = C:\Windows\temp 
xdebug.dump_globals=On 
xdebug.show_exception_trace=On 
xdebug.collect_params=4
```

Try this. Save php.ini. Restart PC.

Comment: OK. Other than that, what changes do I have to make in Netbeans?

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is old, but I had a similar problem, and my setup looked identical to yours except I'm on Ubuntu.  I was able to get it working by simply making it a PHP project within Netbeans; apparently you cannot debug a single file.

You can create a project from an existing codebase and even store the project metadata elsewhere, by doing File->New Project.

Here is a snippet from my PHP.ini file:

```
[xdebug]
zend_extension=xdebug.so
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_host=localhost
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_handler="dbgp"
xdebug.profiler_enable = On
xdebug.profiler_output_dir = /tmp
xdebug.dump_globals=On
xdebug.show_exception_trace=On
xdebug.collect_params=4
```

Make sure you restart the server and Netbeans after editing PHP.ini.